# Checkbox filtering using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to filter using checkbox . but i have some problem . when i select the product category , i am getting the each category item but when i unselect all there arent any product . i want to do this if I unselect category item , i want to show all pruduct how can i do this ? help me please ?

```
<div class="tags">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" />
            Arts
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" />
            Computers
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="health" />
            Health
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />
            Video Games
        </label>
    </div>
    <ul class="results">
        <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
        <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
        <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
        <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
    </ul>
```

jquery ,
,

```
$(document).ready(function () {


            $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
                $('.results > li').hide();
                $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                    $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
                });
            });
        });
```

You can view online with jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/neon38/56MvQ/2/

Comment: .live is deprecated for .on

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/56MvQ/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $('.results > li').toggle('show');
            $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).toggle('show');
            });
        } else{
           $('.results > li').show();
        }
    });
});
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56MvQ/7/)

also toggle('show') give it a nice effect

**`you Can just use Show() and hide() instead of toggle('show')`**

Comment: except toggle("show") will not work the way one would expect on the last show

Comment: @mplungjan okzz i was just checking that

Comment: You can use show(300) for the same effect on the last one

Answer (score 4):

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56MvQ/5/)**

Use **[`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/)** to get the length of selected checkbox. If 0 show all `li`

```
if(!$('div.tags').find('input:checked').length){   //or .length == 0
    $('.results > li').show();
}
```

Comment: I would prefer ==0 to !

Comment: Added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz5QY/1/)

```
  $(document).ready(function () {    
        $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
            $('.results > li').hide();
            if( $('div.tags').find('input:checked').length > 0)
            {
            $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
            }else
                {
                  $('.results > li').show();
                }
          });
     });
```

you just need to check if any option is selected

Comment: how can i put loading img icon panel for this code?

Answer (score 2):

**Put condition like this**    `if($('div.tags').find('input:checked').length > 0)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
                    $('.results > li').hide();
                    if($('div.tags').find('input:checked').length > 0){
                    $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                        $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
                    });
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.results > li').show();
                    }
                });
            });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56MvQ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {

     var count=0; 
     $('.results > li').hide(); 

     $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
        $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
              count=1;
        });
        if(count == 0)
        {
            $('.results > li').show();                    
        }

    });
});
```